# Re-rendering of react leaflet map is happening

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am new to React and developing covid-19 tracker app. I have a country dropdown, when we select any country from dropdown then the api call is made and corona cases, death and recovered cases are displayed using react hooks(useState). This happening using a onCountryChange function;

```
const onCountryChange = async (event) => {
    const countryCode = event.target.value;
    setCountry(countryCode);

    const url =
      countryCode === 'worldwide'
        ? 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all'
        : `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${countryCode}`;
    await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCountry(countryCode);
        setCountryInfo(data);

        setMapCenter([data.countryInfo.lat, data.countryInfo.long]);
        setMapZoom(4);
      });
  };
```

I have brought in the react leaflet map and have a state

```
[ mapCenter, setMapCenter ] = useState({lat: 34.80746, lng: -40.4796})
```

Now in onCountryChange i am setting the
setMapCenter([data.countryInfo.lat, data.countryInfo.long]); but the map is not centering to the selected country. Can any please help me whats wrong here.
here is the githup repo.

```
https://github.com/sohailshams/covid-19-tracker
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you are not changing your lat lon coordinates every time you make the request.

```
 const onCountryChange = async (event) => {
    const countryCode = event.target.value;
    setCountry(countryCode);

    const url =
      countryCode === "worldwide"
        ? "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all"
        : `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${countryCode}`;
    await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setCountryInfo(countryCode);
        setCountryInfo(data);
        const {
          countryInfo: { lat, long },
        } = data;
        setMapCenter({ lat, lng: long }); // here change the coordinates of the selected country
      });
  };
```

Second, use a component to change the map view by passing the new coords as a prop as by changing the center is not sufficient because it is **immutable** on 3.x versions

```
function ChangeMapView({ coords }) {
  const map = useMap();
  map.setView([coords.lat, coords.lng], map.getZoom());

  return null;
}
```

and use it inside your Map component:

```
function Map({ center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <div className='map'>
      <LeafletMap center={center} zoom={zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        <ChangeMapView coords={center} /> //here use it by passing the center coords
      </LeafletMap>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit**

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rerender-react-leaflet-v3x-map-on-country-change-hn8u7)

I used your github code explicitly to reproduce the problem and later
I saw that you have  changed a bit the code.
By using this line

```
setMapCenter([data.countryInfo.lat, data.countryInfo.long]);
```

you are changing the type of your variable which in the first place was an object and suddenly it became an array. You should not do that in my opinion. But in the end if you want to do it just change slightly  ChangeMapView comp to be

```
function ChangeMapView({ coords }) {
  const map = useMap();
  map.setView([coords[0], coords[1], map.getZoom());

  return null;
}
```

and again your issue is resolved

Comment: Thanks for answer, actually it does changed the coordinates when we change the country. You can see with console.log(data.countryInfo.lat) console.log(data.countryInfo.long) and when I set the value to setMapCenter=([data.countryInfo.lat, data.countryInfo.long]); it should change the map position as i am passing center and zoom as a prop to the Map component.

Comment: Does not matter because you are passing `center={mapCenter}` to Map component so `mapCenter` variable has the coordinates you should change in order to receive them on Map and change the map view. In a different scenario you need to change the variable you are passing to Map. `setMapCenter` is not used anywhere on your github code

Comment: Thanks man really appreciate your effort and help. But if I just add the following code in Map.js then the map is updated and positioned to the updated lat and long.
function ChangeMap({ center, zoom }) {
  const map = useMap();
  map.setView(center, zoom);
  return null;
}

Comment: Don't you want to center the map based on the selected country's coordinates? What do you want to achieve then?

Comment: Yes I want to center the map based on the selected country and this function also does it. however I like your approach and will go with that. Thanks

Comment: It is helpful I am sorry if you felt that way.

Comment: no problem. Please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you are new to SO what you have to do if an answer solved your issue